# @Controller returns empty page with "ok"

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

I'm trying to save a file with js from modal window. I save it all right but then I'm redirected to the page with only "ok" written on it.
I mean this: [image]

My js looks like:

```
var name = $('#upload-track-name').val();
var description = $('#upload-track-description').val();
var file = document.getElementById('input-file').files[0];

var isValidate = true;

if (name.trim() == '') {
    $('#error-upload-track-name').show();
    isValidate = false;
}
if (!file) {
    $('#error-upload-track-file').show();
    isValidate = false;
}
if (!isValidate) {
    return;
}

$.ajax({
    url: '/tracks/upload',//I see this empty page on this url
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        file: file,
        name: name,
        description: description
    },
    success: function (data){

        if (data == 1) {
            $('#error-upload-track-file').hide();
            $('#error-upload-track-name').show();
        } else if (data == 2) {
            $('#error-upload-track-name').hide();
            $('#error-upload-track-file').show();
        } else {
            $('#modal-upload-success').show();
        }
    })
```

And here is my @Controller:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = TracksGeopointsRoutes.UPLOAD, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String uploadTrack(@RequestParam MultipartFile file,
              @RequestParam String name,
              @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "") String description,
                  Model model){

    TracksGeopointsDoc tracksGeopointsDoc = new TracksGeopointsDoc();

    if (name.equals("")) {
        return "1";
    }
    if (file.getSize() == 0 || file == null){
        return "2";
    }
    ObjectId fileId = fileService.saveWithDelete(file, null);
    tracksGeopointsDoc.setFile(fileId);
    tracksGeopointsDoc.setUploadDate(new Date());
    tracksGeopointsDoc.setName(name);
    tracksGeopointsDoc.setDescription(description);
    tracksGeopointsService.saveTrack(tracksGeopointsDoc);
    try {
        File convFile = tracksGeopointsService.convert(file);

        String s = convFile.getAbsolutePath();

        mySaxParser.setUpMySaxParser(convFile.getAbsolutePath(), tracksGeopointsDoc.getId(), convFile.getName());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "ok";

}
```

I suspect that it is because of @ResponseBody annotation. And if I am right can anyone tell me how can I avoid this.

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen after the File is uploaded?

Comment: What I'm guessing is that you want to show another view(or return another view) after you get 'ok' in success. If you get 'ok' in success function then you can change the navigate to another location using window.location.href or if you want another view in that same page then you initiate another ajax call.

Comment: @Obi Wan - PallavJha Added a pic to show what I mean

Comment: @Sanjay Rawat Added a pic to show what I mean

Comment: @Dexa That's what I'm telling you.you can either wait to get 'ok' in your response then fire another ajax method to load a page in the same view or you can change your browser's location to the path you want using window.location.href

Comment: @Obi Wan - PallavJha Could you please tell me how I "fire another ajax method to load a page in the same view". I tried using location.reload(true) but it haven't worked...